# Jupyter notebook input() not showing after using IPython display(markdown())

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, ipython

I am trying to build a Chatbot using Jupyter Notebook on Google Colab. I am using IPython Markdown to better segregate the user conversations. User will key in their message using `input()` while the bot responses are IPython `display(markdown())`.

I am facing issues when i tried to print a starting messages (bot output before a user input). This error occurs approximately 50% of the time I run the script. No errors are faced if I did not print out the starting message. I have tried restarting the kernel but to no avail.

Does anyone know what is the reason for this and how I can fix it?

This is an example of a successful case.
[image: Successful example]

This is an example of a failed case. As you can see, the code is running indefinitely on the `input()` line.
[image: Failed to load]

This is the sample code, where `input()` box does not pop up at times.

```
from IPython.display import Markdown, display

display(Markdown("*Alex:* Hello."))

input(">> You: ")
```

Comment: I had the same issue but when trying to display an image from graphviz. If you add a time.sleep() in between the display and input statements it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a kind of bug in Jupyter notebook, described in the past years by many programmers. I was facing the same problem. After several tests I have found (at least in my code) that the problem disappears if `print()` functions are removed before `input()`.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for your input! There seems to be no direct answer to this bug for now..

Comment: @Goh Jia Yi It's been a few years since this answer, but you mentioned that this is a known bug -- do you have any links to existing GitHub issues, etc. talking about this bug? I'm facing the same issue, and so far this Stack Overflow post is the only place I can find that mentions it

Comment: I'm sorry for not replying earlier: I saw some comments in different forums concerning this bug, nothing in GitHub.